# Handle form data with array PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have an HTML form that looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="ideal_test.php">
<input type="text" name="member[email]" placeholder="email" /><br />
<input type="text" name="member[country_code]" placeholder="country code" /><br />
<input type="text" name="member[first_name]" placeholder="first name" /><br />
<input type="text" name="member[last_name]" placeholder="last name" /><br />
<input type="text" name="member[street]" placeholder="street" /><br />
<input type="text" name="member[house_nr]" placeholder="house number" /><br />
<input type="text" name="member[houseNrExtension]" placeholder="house number addition" /><br />
<input type="text" name="member[postcode]" placeholder="postcode" /><br />
<input type="text" name="member[city]" placeholder="city" /><br />
<input type="text" name="member[phone]" placeholder="phone number" /><br />
<input type="text" name="member[birthday]" placeholder="birthday" /><br />
<input type="text" name="member[gender]" placeholder="gender" /><br />
<input type="text" name="member[ideal_bank]" placeholder="iDeal bank" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="payment" value="ideal" />

<input type="submit" value="Test iDeal API call" />
```

The reason the form has been made this way is because I use an API that has to receive the data in this format. When I change the form action to the API URL, it works, however, sometimes I have to handle the form data myself with my own PHP and I don't know how I should process this form with PHP.

This is what I've tried:

```
$data = $_POST[ 'member' ];

foreach( $data AS $row ) {
    echo $row . '<br />';
}
```

This shows all the data nicely separated by the `<br />`. However, I need to access each input separately, so I've tried this to achieve that:

```
foreach( $data AS $row ) {
    echo $row['email'] . '<br />';
}
```

When I do this, it displays the first letter of each input, also separated by `<br />`. How can I loop through the `member[]` array and get every input separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$data` is an array.
 So if you want to access each input separately You don't need to do it in **foreach** loop.
 You simply print it as normal array variable. Like this:

```
<?php
     echo $data['email'];
     echo $data['first_name'];
     // Like this.
?>
```